# Firebase Cloud Messaging deleting notification

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working with `.net core` and `Firebase Cloud Messaging`

I was able to add a scheduled notification on Firebase. Now I need to add the ability to cancel or delete this scheduled notification.

Isn't this possible? I've searched `FCM` but there's no API for deleting or canceling a scheduled notificaiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only way to schedule messages without a custom server is through the Firebase console, I'm going to assume you've used that.

In that case, to cancel a message you will also have to do so through the console.

1. Go to the [Firebase Cloud Messaging console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/notification) for your project.
2. You'll see a list of notifications for your project:

   [image]
3. Click the little three-dot overflow menu ⠇ on the right of the scheduled message.

   [image]
4. Click <kbd>Delete notification</kbd> in the menu

Comment: If I set the `sentDate` of a notification for tomorrow, won't be scheduled for tomorrow? I'm using  `.net core` and I'm sending a notification by posting to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` with a `sendDate` of now or later based on the user choice. So what if a user decided to cancel this scheduled notification??

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to schedule sending FCM messages through the API. I also see no mention of a `sendDate`  parameter in these docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: Hey @MohamadMousheimish. Any update on this? Since I don't know how you're scheduling the messages to be sent (which the API doesn't support afaik, but the console does), it's hard to help further.

Comment: Hello Frank, I think you helped me enough but sorry for not replying we're at a holiday now. So will discuss this with my team as soon as we get back. Thanks a lot for your reply, time and considerations.